# Tengo inconveniente en mi función hecha en C# estoy realizando un proceso de envío de archivo por TFTP

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, c#-8.0

Al ejecutar esta función echa en C# me presenta el siguiente mensaje, "tftp" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.". al ver que no funcionaba agregue directamente la ruta del ejecutable tftp.exe y no funciono, adicional comprobé por CMD si envía el archivo a mi servidor y si funciona. me pueden ayudar por favor

Adjunto código:

```
public string Proceso_TFTP(string NameArchivo)
{
  string Result = "";
  string ServiceTftp = Properties.Settings.Default.ServiceTftp;
  string ArchivoCfg = Properties.Settings.Default.ArchivoCfg;

  string comando = $"tftp -i {ServiceTftp} put {ArchivoCfg}{NameArchivo}";
  Console.WriteLine("Proceso_TFTP_COMANDO: " + comando);

  using (Process process = new Process())
  {
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/c {comando}";
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    // Solicitar elevación de privilegios (ejecutar como administrador)
    process.StartInfo.Verb = "rutas";

    process.Start();

    // Capturar la salida estándar
    Result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    process.WaitForExit();
  }

  return Result;
}
```

Comment: pues o agregas al path ese programa, o escribis exactamente la ruta donde esta.. ya sabias la solucion...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! de paso, verifica que tengas permisos para llegar a ese archivo

Comment: Hola Gbianchi muchas gracias por tu respuesta, te comento que hice eso pero el resultado es el mismo, también pensé que era porque no estoy ejecutando el aplicativo como administrador pero me da el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Lo realice con la librería tftp.Net.
adjunto el codigo:

namespace ConsoleAppTftpTest
{

```
class TftpClientExample
{
    private static AutoResetEvent TransferFinishedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

       
        string serverIp = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";  /// aqui la Ip del servidor          
        int serverPort = 69; // Puerto


        // Nombre remoto del archivo en el servidor TFTP
        string remoteFileName = "archivo.txt";
        string localFileName = @"D:\archivo.txt";


        TftpClient tftpClient = new TftpClient(serverIp, serverPort);
        try
        {               
            var transfer = tftpClient.Upload(remoteFileName);
            //Capture the events that may happen during the transfer
            //transfer.OnProgress += new TftpProgressHandler(transfer_OnProgress);
            transfer.OnFinished += new TftpEventHandler(transfer_OnFinshed);
            transfer.OnError += new TftpErrorHandler(transfer_OnError);


            Stream fileToUpload = File.OpenRead(localFileName);
            transfer.Start(fileToUpload);

            //Wait for the transfer to finish
            TransferFinishedEvent.WaitOne();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error general: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    static void transfer_OnProgress(ITftpTransfer transfer, TftpTransferProgress progress)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Transfer running. Progress: " + progress);
    }

    static void transfer_OnError(ITftpTransfer transfer, TftpTransferError error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Transfer failed: " + error);
        TransferFinishedEvent.Set();
    }

    static void transfer_OnFinshed(ITftpTransfer transfer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Transfer succeeded.");
        TransferFinishedEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

}